# Constructor injection in Spring

Tags: spring, constructor-injection

I'm working on a code where a class A is constructing an object of class B using parameterized constructor of class B. As of now, class B is not yet spring injected. The requirement is that I should always have a new non-singleton object of class B. The code somewhat looks like this:

```
class A{

private List<ClassB> classBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();

void parseInfo(File f, Element e){
ClassB b = new ClassB(this,f,e);
classBList.add(b);
}

}
```

How should my spring-config look like if i have to inject class B using spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the bean as prototype

```
<!-- A bean definition with singleton scope -->
  <bean id="classBBean" class="ClassB" scope="prototype"/>
```

Use applicationContext [getBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) method to create bean each time by passing arguments.

```
class A implements ApplicationContextAware{
           private List<ClassB> classBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
           @Autowired               
           private ApplicationContext appContext;
           void parseInfo(File f, Element e){
                    ClassB b = (ClassB)appContext.getBean("classBBean",new Object[]{this,f,e});
                    classBList.add(b);
             }

       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain what does new Object[]{this,f,e} do? Does it call the constructor of class B?

Comment: new Object[]{this,f,e} are constructor arguments. You can refer getBean(String name, Object[] args) method javadoc. Hyperlink is provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about Spring scopes

Basically, you need to declare your bean with scope **prototype** if it's a general spring application

```
<!-- A bean definition with singleton scope -->
<bean id="..." class="..." scope="prototype">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

or request, if it's a web spring application

```
<!-- A bean definition with singleton scope -->
<bean id="..." class="..." scope="request">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

For more examples look at
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm